# Как сравнить два ArrayList`a по их содержимому?

Tags: java

Я хочу сравнит два листа, по их содержимому в объекте.
Если объект из первого листа найден во втором, то ввести его.
Но мой код не работает, выдает exception: java heap memory

Вопрос: Что тут не так и как правильно реализовать?
код:

```
 private List<PaymentRBS> rbsList;
private List<PaymentPartner> partnerList;

public void compare() {
    ArrayList<PaymentPartner> found = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<PaymentPartner> notFound = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (PaymentRBS rbs : rbsList) {
        for (PaymentPartner partner : partnerList){
            if (partner.getAccount().equals(rbs.getAccount()) && partner.getSum() == rbs.getSum()){
                found.add(partner);
            }
            else{
                notFound.add(partner);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `compare` должен возвращать какой-либо из списков `found`/`notFound` (или некий объект, позволяющий вернуть оба таких списка, например `Map<Boolean, List<PaymentPartner>>`).  Также для метода следует выбрать более подходящее название типа `findMatches`, `findNonMatches`.

Также списки `rbsList`, `partnerList` должны передаваться в метод `compare` как аргументы.

Добавление в список `notFound` следует выполнять только если из списка `partnerList` не был обнаружен в списке `rbs` (после цикла)

Примерная реализация, возвращающая оба списка в `Map`:

```java
public Map<Boolean, List<PaymentPartner>> findMatches(
    List<PaymentRBS> rbsList, List<PaymentPartner> partnerList) 
{
    Map<Boolean, List<PaymentPartner>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (PaymentPartner partner :  partnerList) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (PaymentRBS rbs : rbsList) {
            if (partner.getAccount().equals(rbs.getAccount()) 
                && partner.getSum() == rbs.getSum()) {
                found = true;
                break;  // нашли первое совпадение
            }
        }
        result.computeIfAbsent(found, (k) -> new ArrayList<>())
              .add(partner);
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Что касается ошибки `OutOfMemory`, она может быть вызвана, когда один из списков слишком большой (например, вычитывается из таблицы в БД, содержащей миллионы объемных записей, состоящие из десятка-другого полей, хотя фактически для сравнения используются только два поля).  Нужно увеличивать объем памяти, доступный для кучи Heap и оптимизировать объём данных.

Answer (score 0):

Длинновато для комментария:

про exception - отлаживайте, проверяйте, какие объекты не созданы, например, в данном куске кода не видно создания списков из верхних строчек (может, где-то оно и есть).

Кроме того, имеется логическая ошибка  - в список `notfound` добавляется каждый `partner`, не совпадающий с **текущим** `rbs`, но ведь он может совпасть с другим элементом `rbsList`. В данном случае `notfound` будут содержать много одинаковых копий

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться JUnit:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

assertArrayEquals(found.toArray(), notFound.toArray());
```